# 1 coin found in Sachsen Anhalt Germany, please help me to identify the coin

Tags: identification, numismatics

My son also found the same coin in spiel platz while he was playing. Have you got any further infornation about your 2 coins?[image]

Comment: Is this a coin? Is this metal? Can you provide: a description of the material,  a picture of the the backside, a ruler sth to measure/scale this, and the exact location (town/city) where this was found?

Comment: Have a look at the accepted answer of this question: [Please help identify these old coins found in Germany?](https://history.stackexchange.com/a/59031/38607)

Comment: @MarkJohnson If it is not the accepted but *alternative* answer, this is a perfect duplicate, cf https://pshlaw.ru/ru/item/6028228 ?

Comment: @LangLangC May very well be since the irregularities on the top and bottom right hand side seem to be identical, which the 2 of the original photo, which were also corroded, doesn't seem to have.

Answer (score 2):

Answer: This is a low-quality modern reproduction (fake) of an antique coin. You can analyze the coin and see it for yourself: The ridges are meant to suggest a heavily corroded surface but the flat and smooth background indicates no corrosion at all. The lower surfaces have been painted a uniform black/grey color. The raised surfaces have the consistent dull grey color of cheap metal. One can't tell from a photograph, but the coin might have very light feel, indicating a cheap mixture of zinc and other metals, possibly including toxic lead.

In contrast, a real ancient coin would not have uniform flat surfaces (like the ones you see above). It would not have a painted background. Its raised surfaces would show more polishing and extra wear closer to the outer edges. It would have the weight and feel of "a real coin."

As pointed out by @LangLangC, it is usually possible to find [nearly identical copies](https://17.img.avito.st/640x480/5886087117.jpg) of modern fakes online. Ancient minting techniques showed greater variation from the outset. Centuries of aging only increases the variations from one coin to another.

Comment: + The degradation is especially notable to be artificial if *identical* ones appear more than once https://17.img.avito.st/640x480/5886087117.jpg ? The distance between lower surface and features also looks quite big…

Comment: If you like the comment, and the link, and incorporate it all, perhaps via a quote (with convincing pic), we surely might cleanup the comments (which can be deleted anyway) ;)