# Need help identifying this coin

Tags: identification, numismatics

[image: need help identify]

[image]

I have had this coin for a few months and still no luck

Comment: Both pics of the same side. Google image search answers this directly. Look [at Etsy](https://www.etsy.com/listing/984752538/hand-poured-999-fs-spanish-pirate?gpla=1&gao=1&&utm_source=google&utm_medium=cpc&utm_campaign=shopping_us_c-art_and_collectibles-collectibles-coins&utm_custom1=_k_Cj0KCQjwvLOTBhCJARIsACVldV24mNbzrOMBpXUi9SAJqJZVaNZNFKrPtCkjUI3eddAWVs2Wqp57Fn0aAu31EALw_wcB_k_&utm_content=go_12573353456_119955062856_507558170305_pla-353500745642_c__984752538_443254578&utm_custom2=12573353456&gclid=Cj0KCQjwvLOTBhCJARIsACVldV24mNbzrOMBpXUi9SAJqJZVaNZNFKrPtCkjUI3eddAWVs2Wqp57Fn0aAu31EALw_wcB)

Comment: Fixed the pics.

Comment: Looks to be the same coins (and identical shape)  discussed in [this question](https://history.stackexchange.com/q/59030/16951).